# Migrating ios In App Purchase Verification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I build an ios app originally in IOS 6. I'm trying to migrate it to IOS 7+ / IOS 8, and I'm having trouble with In-App Purchase verification.

The verification is done server side. After each purchases, I send the  SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt as a Base64 string to my server (nodeJS), which then uses IAP_VERIFIER (https://github.com/pcrawfor/iap_verifier) to verify the receipt.

Since SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt is depricated, I want to change it to the new NSBundle.appStoreReceiptURL, however, when I send that receipt to my server for verification, the apple verification says it is invalid. Comparing the Base64 string of the transacationReceipt and the appStoreReceipt , they are completely different, the appStoreReceipt being much bigger.

How do I verify a single In-App purchase receipt with the new method?

Comment: The base64 results WILL be different because the appStoreReceiptURL contents is unified for all the transactions, so you can't use the difference in encoded info (alone) to diagnose your issue. Perhaps you should note any detailed errors or other misbehavior. Oh, and look at this (Apple's docs on the process): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not a Sandbox/Production issue?

[Check this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html), question 15: What url should I use to verify my receipt ?

And make sure you do not hit the wrong environment.
Also check the base64 encoding with different tool to make sure you don't use a buggy encoding function.